# HEVC (x265) encoding in Instagram videos?

Tags: instagram, video-encoding, transcoding, hevc, libx265

Is Instagram using x265 as an encoding format to further compress and reformat the uploaded videos for mobile devices?

I tried doing ffprobe on the video downloaded (after sniffing the https traffic and getting the url from the GET body), but it turned out to be x264. Not sure if at all they are using x265 as an encoding format. 
Any help would be appreciated in this regard, if not instagram then any other video streaming social sites which are doing the same?

Comment: I believe that the way they encode videos on their backend is strictly confidential. You can of course assume what they could do analyzing the downloaded video, but that's it. Is highly unlikely that someone would tell you exactly how they do it, simply because you could just grab that information and create a new streaming service that uses that encoding but, idk, is better in other ways, so people might want to choose it (and of course Instagram, like any other companies, don't want this)

Comment: @Jimi: was just hoping someone from instagram or facebook could give atleast a yes or no to my question.